# I set permission_required as "is_staff" and I got error 403 permission denied

Tags: python, django, django-views, permission-denied

I developped a webapp with Django and I want to protect a class view with permission. It should be only authorized for admin so I added this :
`permission_required = 'is_staff'`

But when I try to access to the view with my admin profiles (and I set their status as staff) I got this error : 403 Forbidden, permission denied.

The fact is that if I try with super user profile it works. So I don't understand why 'is_staff' is recognized as 'is_superuser'

Thank's for reading

Answer (score 1):

`permission_required = 'is_staff'`  is not recognized as a superuser.The reason is superuser(with the status `is_superuser=True`) will have all the permissions of the system by default, so superuser will be able to access the any view.

If you want to give access the view to the admin(superuser) only.

In function view you can do this

```
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
    @user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
    def your_view():
```

And in class based view you can use the [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin)

If you want to see more details on permissions you can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)